# SQL Server Trigger to alter different table

Tags: sql-server

I’m trying to create a trigger to change the value of a column in table B if it finds the information in a column in table A.

An example of my database is below:

[TableA],
itemID

[TableB],
itemID
itemInStock

Once a user creates an entry in Table A declaring an `itemID`, the trigger needs to change the `TableB.itemInStock` column to ‘Yes’

I’m still learning SQL so excuse me if I’ve missed something, let me know if you need any more info.

I understand there are better ways of doing this but I've been told I need to do this using a trigger.

I've attempted a few different things, but as it stands nothing is working, below is the current solution I have however this updates all `itemInStock` rows to 'Yes', where as I only want the ones to update where the `TableB.itemID` matches the itemID entered in `TableA`.

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [itemAvailability] ON  [dbo].[TableA] FOR
 INSERT
 AS 
    BEGIN
     UPDATE [dbo].[TableB] set itemInStock = 'Yes' WHERE 
        TableB.itemID = itemID
  END
```

Comment: Yes, there are definitely better ways - most of them involving *not having an `ItemInStock` column at all*. `ItemInStock` is *derived* data. You can compute it *at any time* from other data you already hold. All you do by storing derived data is *introduce* the opportunity for it to be inconsistent with the other data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yep I know, I've been given a specific spec to follow and this is how they have asked me to do it. Don't worry it's just a practice piece, my awful SQL isn't going into production anywhere :)

Comment: Yeah, I've never understood why they come up with such *awful* examples as motivating examples for features. "Here's a Victorian chair where one of the legs is slightly wobbly. To fix it, we'll be driving 3 inch decking screws into the item using a sledgehammer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems -

1. you're not looking at the Inserted pseudo table which contains the
   newly inserted rows
2. you're assuming the trigger is called once per row - this is not the
   case, the trigger is called once per statement and the Inserted
   pseudo table will contain multiple rows - and you need to deal with
   that

So, your code should look like this -

```
ALTER TRIGGER [itemAvailability] ON  [dbo].[TableA]
FOR INSERT
AS
UPDATE TB
SET itemInStock = 'Yes'
FROM [dbo].[TableB] TB JOIN inserted I
on TB.itemID = I.itemID
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much, the only change I had to make was adding in FOR INSERT at the end of the first line.